# Extract a list of HTML attribute values using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, list, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Given a page with a list of elements, e.g. `<input>` elements, all of which have a common class, e.g. `category-checkbox`, how might I extract the values of all of these elements to a list using beautifulsoup? E.g.:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="category-checkbox" value="apples" />
<input type="checkbox" class="category-checkbox" value="pears" />
<input type="checkbox" class="category-checkbox" value="oranges" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up mapping the elements to a new list:

```
# assume the html variable is a beautifulsoup object
input_values = [
    element.get('value') for element in
    html.findAll('input', {"class": "category-checkbox"})
]
# category_input_values is now [ 'apples', 'pears', 'oranges' ]
```

Comment: Have you answered your own question 2 seconds after you posted it?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso yep :) You know the "Answer your own question, Q&A style" button you can hit on SO questions? That's what I did, in case it helps others. I didn't find the exact answer I was looking for when I was working out how to do it. Plus if anybody can come up with a nicer way to do it I'd be happy to see.